# Incidence matrix in a graph, meaning of $B^TB$

Tags: graph-theory, spectral-graph-theory

If $B\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times e}$ is the incidence matrix corresponding to a graph with $n$ vertices and $e$ edges, we know that $BB^T\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ is the graph Laplacian matrix.

I am curious that if there is any special meaning of the matrix $B^TB\in\mathbb{R}^{e\times e}$.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I am not sure. But I am curious why it's the Laplacian of the dual graph.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, "special" is maybe an overstatement, because the meaning is really boring: If we consider edges of an undirected graph as two-element subsets of its vertex set, then
$$(B^T B)_{e,e'} = \sum_v B_{v,e} B_{v,e'} = \#\{v | v \text{ is incident to $e$ and $e'$}\}=|e\cap e'|$$
which is $2\cdot 1_{n\times n}+$ the adjacency matrix of the line graph of $G$.

And and a slightly more complicated, but similarly boring formula can be derived directly from the definition if you consider directed graphs instead.